# Pre-install and deliver app on sd card

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me, mobile, symbian

I need to deliver an app on sd card, and need to make it start automatically after insertion of the card.

What I want to ask is, is this possible to achieve this for the operating systems android, symbian, blackberry and j2me supported phones?

I know that symbian supports pre-installment but how to do auto-start? And on android before version 2.2 non-sd card apps don't supported as i know.

Comment: What changed with android version was the ability to install applications to the SD card instead of the more limited unix-file-system internal storage.  There hasn't been any major change between android re-versions in the constraints on installing from the SD card or any source other than the android market, though there is a carrier-dependent difference in the AT&T is more restrictive than most others.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can do this (atleast with my experience with android) without asking for the user's permission. Instead of automatically installing the app, you can start an intent which then asks the user to accept the permissions to install the app. You may also want to look at putting the app on the market (unless it's private) it's only $25 and you can upload an unlimited amount of apps for the rest of your life.

Comment: you mean, putting the .apk file and tell the user to select it to install? if not, how to auto-start that intent?

Comment: You cannot auto-start the installation process, period.  Also they won't be able to install from the SDK card unless they have enabled non-market application sources in their settings, a choice they may be reluctant to make and which AT&T currently denies its customers as an option.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to deliver an app on sd card, and need to make it start automatically after insertion of the card.

On Android, that is not possible without custom firmware.

Also, bear in mind that some of those devices do not have SD card slots of any form.

Comment: thanks. but i'll target only those ones that have sd-card slot.